# Javascript Structural Highlighting for Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, formatting, visual-studio-extensions

I'm using 'StructureAdornment' extension for visual studio which creates a line for matching barces. It works good but it only works for C# files. I was wondering if there was any extension which does the same job for javascript files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try these extension JScript Editor Extensions.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/872d27ee-38c7-4a97-98dc-0d8a431cc2ed/

you can customize your shortcut.

Comment: Adds support for automatically highlighting the matching opening or closing brace to the one currently at the cursor. Supports matching parenthesis: (), square brackets: [], and curly braces: {}. Braces in strings, comments and regular expression literals are ignored

Comment: got resharper..which does must of those things.

Answer (score 0):

[Indent Guides for Visual Studio](http://indentguide.codeplex.com/releases/view/110312)

Personally tried and tested on Visual Studio 2010

Works on javascript, c#, vb, cshtml, vbhtml, files.