# Notepad++ indent guide all wrong

Tags: view, formatting, notepad++, edit, indentation

I wanted to add some auto-indenting to Notepad++ to my Javascript code. That semi-worked: it now indents the previous line's amount, but doesn't indent any extra for new scopes. Now though, my indent guides are all wrong: every extra character creates an indent guide on the lines below it, instead of indent guides only for extra scope. It's like this in all file types, not just Javascript. Help!

Note: I was on 5.9.x, now on 6.5.2. Doesn't do anything. System Restore didn't do anything either.

Here is a screenshot that shows the problem: [image]

Comment: Ok, so one mystery solved is the missing auto-indent. Turns out that it is supposed to just maintain indentation and is mis-labeled. Installing NppAutoIndent helped for that particular problem.

Comment: you can add your finding as an answer and mark it after two days

Comment: Thanks.. I know. There still might be a solution for the whole problem.

Comment: Although only one answer can be marked, there is not only one correct answer, but all answers together make a **good answer**. Personally I'm skeptical about code indenting capabilities of N++. I needed them for T-SQL and the only way was a special plugin (I'm still not satisfied). N++ is strong in text editing, not in code insight. Try getting another IDE if you wish intelligent indent guides.  Regarding your screenshot: you can set tab width in options to 4 or 8 to set number of characters between vertical guides.

Comment: The problem was that the indent guide is not an indent guide. It just throws in dotted lines between characters. I thought it would be an actual indent guide -- something that shows dotted lines for outer scopes.

Comment: I haven't seen such a indent guide in any editor. Did you?

Comment: Maybe not. I thought I have. But perhaps I was mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312059/javascript-structural-highlighting-for-visual-studio).
This is not addressing indentation, but [structural highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYfh1.gif), what is superset of indentation in many cases.

I'm sorry this is for visual studio, but most answers I could find lead there. Basic version of VisualStudio should be for free download. Optionally you can [search Google for "javascript indent guides"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=javascript+indent+guides&oq=javascript+indent+guides) to find some other editor.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe I can find something for Notepad++... or, at least I know what the technical term is now.